# Scraping an aspx page with Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to scrape data off of an aspx page?

I am trying to do this with Ruby on Rails and have installed the mechanize gem.
I want to be able to find a form and submit it, but when i try to do it on the console, i cannot see the form. It works with other websites just not aspx.

I was following this [guide.](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html)
I want to put the address in there and submit. 
I can get the data i need after that with nokogiri, but i need to get the data first.

This is what i have tried.

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('https://Page.aspx')

pp page
```

From there you will be able to see that the input field for the address is not there.

If you guys could help me out, that would be amazing.

Comment: Q: Is it possible to scrape data off an .aspx page?  A: Yes, of course!  It's all HTML!  SUGGESTION: "view, source" the page(s) in question in a browser; try to figure out "what's missing".  In particular, note if the "form" (as perceived by the user) is actually an HTML "form" with HTML <input>" tags ... or "something else" (like a bunch of interactive Javascript, for example).

Comment: There is an input in there but there is no form.